Generic String to Enum validator
I have to validate a CSV file with a bunch of columns. Some of them need to map to various enum types. I know how to validate string value against a specific enum type, but I would like to have a generic validation method where I would pass in string value and enum type and get validation result. So far I have this:
private boolean valitateSomeSpecificEnum(String value) {
    try {
        SomeSpecificEnum.valueOf(value);
        return true;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

Is it possible to have something like:
private boolean valitateAgainstTheEnum(String value, Enum<?> theEnum) {
    try {
        theEnum.valueOf(value);
        return true;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

Note I'm using Enum<?> in the method signature just to make it clear what I want to achieve, I'm aware that as written it would not work.
Then I could call it like so
valitateTheEnum("foo", SomeSpecificEnum.class);

is this even possible?

What is in SomeSpecificEnum?

It's a some specific enum class I already have.

See this

@Ajant questions in [so] should be specific and include a [mre], so you should include such classes in your question.

It's slightly mysterious why you need to validate though, since the usual outcome is simple bean mapping

I'm processing the csv file manually. When I read the file I get bunch of arrays of strings. I need to perform various validations (mail format, non-empty etc.) on various columns and to create very specific response format. I'm not aware of any way to do automatic mapping of such data, but I'd be glad to explore any suggestions you might have

Based on the link provided by g00se's in a comment, I've come up with this and it works:
private boolean valitateAgainstTheEnum(String value, Class<? extends Enum> theEnum) {
    try {
        Enum.valueOf(theEnum, value);
        return true;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

Only question remains if there is a more elegant way to do it

Did you try using streams?

Not sure I understand the question

You can try Stream.anyMatch().
Like:
private static <E extends Enum<E>> boolean validate(String value, Class<E> enumClass) {
    return Stream.of(enumClass.getEnumConstants()).anyMatch(e -> e.name().equals(value));
}

NOTE: I changed the generic signature to prevent 'raw type' warning.

Why would you stream something when you can access it directly without looping constructs?

This question was marked as a duplicated. You could submit your answer to the original question.

@g00se Because OP needs a boolean result instead of enum member, and Enum.valueOf doesn't return null but throws an IllegalArgumentException if the value is not found.

Sorry I don't understand that even remotely

Note that Enum.valueOf is a map lookup, whereas you do a linear search on a clone of an array.
